# SQlite db remote file Connection

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB hosted on my local network

---

I want to connect to these SQLite DB through python with the following code

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('http://172.24.3.171:18080/db/SCdatabase.sq3')
cursor1 = conn.execute("select* from OlcConfig_Actual where LogReporterPointer = '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'")

rows = cursor1.fetchall()
lista =[]

if len(rows) >= 1:
    for eachrow in rows:

        for eachcol in eachrow:
               lista.append(str(eachcol))

    print lista

print "Opened database successfully";
```

---

But I get an error that says:

OperationalError: unable to open database file

Can someone help me out with the error on the code?

Answer (score 1):

SQlite does not communicate over HTTP, it requires a file on your local file system.  If you can "reach" your file with `ls` (on *X) or `dir` (on Windows) then use the full path to the file in your connect statement.